# cocoapods not installed in macos big sur flutter

Tags: macos, flutter

it's my first using macOS I downloaded big sur version and I had install flutter
when I run `flutter doctor` I see this problem [image]

[image]

Idk how to solve it
and i saw many answers here but still not working

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i found the answer here in some topic I don't remember

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it fixed when i install homebrow

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an M1 mac, you can download ffi first by this command:

```
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
```

then run pod commands like this :

```
arch -x86_64 pod install
```

Comment: no, I'm using an Intel processor